# CSS modules using Create-React-App + Material UI combo

Tags: material-ui, create-react-app, css-modules

I am having trouble understanding the docs given on the material UI site, for overriding the css styles when using css modules. If there is conflicting styles, i need to use the ***!important*** hack to overwrite their styles.

I have tried to follow their suggestion of

> css injection order

so that my custom css (using css modules) comes *after* the material UI css.

The link I have tried to follow is
https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#css-injection-order

If anyone is able to give me a simple step my step solution of how to do this with a component or a solution using *codesandbox* it would be very helpful.

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code for your `<head>` in your `index.html` file?

Comment: Can you also provide the component that initiates `<JssProvider>`?

Comment: @Chimera.Zen Please see example of index.html. Not sure where I can find <JssProvider/> component. Can you elaborate? 
https://codepen.io/arhoy/pen/gQwdOe?editors=1010#